# Kendo UI List View - switches model instance on Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a simple Kendo List view, with static data from an array of four `Note` objects

```
var notes = [{"note_id":1,"content":"This is Note 1","created":"2019-05-08 00:39:34"},
            {"note_id":2,"content":"This is note 2","created":"2015-06-04 15:49:26"},
            {"note_id":3,"content":"This is note 3","created":"2015-06-03 15:49:26"},
            {"note_id":4,"content":"This is note 4","created":"2015-06-02 15:49:26"}];
```

I've got separate `template`s for display and edit of the Notes

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="NoteTemplate">
        <div class="product-view k-widget">
            <dl>
                <dt>#:kendo. toString(created, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")#</dt>
                <dd>#=(content)#</dd>
            </dl>
            <div class="edit-buttons">
                <a class="k-button k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-edit"></span></a>
                <a class="k-button k-delete-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="type_id" value="0" data-bind="value:type_id" />
</script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="NoteEditTemplate">
        <div class="product-view k-widget">
            <dl>
                <dt>#:kendo. toString(created, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")#</dt>
                <dd>
                    <div data-bind="value:content">
                #=content#
                    </div>
                </dd>

            <div class="edit-buttons">
                <a class="k-button k-update-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-check"></span></a>
                <a class="k-button k-cancel-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-cancel"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</script>
```

The issue is, when the user clicks the "pencil" icon to edit "Note 2", the edit template is rendered **but with the model for Note 3**

If the user cancels edit more, they again see the display template rendering Note 2

So it seems like the Kendo component is switching from Note 2 to note 3 when we go into edit mode... Why is it doing this?

See the running demo here:
https://dojo.telerik.com/oNosOCUv/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made 3 changes:-

Adding schema to the datasource.

Closing dl tag in EditNoteTemplate.

**Move the hidden input into the the parent div, because Kendo is assigning the data uid to this element.**
[image: Look at the HTML elements rendered]

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="NoteTemplate">
        <div class="product-view k-widget">
            <dl>
                <dt>#:kendo. toString(created, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")#</dt>
                <dd >#=(content)#</dd>
                <input type="hidden" name="type_id" value="0" data-bind="value:type_id" />
            </dl>
            <div class="edit-buttons">
                <a class="k-button k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-edit"></span></a>
                <a class="k-button k-delete-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>      
</script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="NoteEditTemplate">
        <div class="product-view k-widget">
            <dl>
                <dt>#:kendo. toString(created, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")#</dt>
                <dd>
                    <div data-bind="value:content">
                        #=content#
                    </div>
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <div class="edit-buttons">
                <a class="k-button k-update-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-check"></span></a>
                <a class="k-button k-cancel-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-cancel"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</script>

  <script>

    var notes = [
                        {"note_id":1,"content":"This is Note 1","created":"2019-05-08 00:39:34"},
                        {"note_id":2,"content":"This is note 2","created":"2015-06-04 15:49:26"},
                        {"note_id":3,"content":"This is note 3","created":"2015-06-03 15:49:26"},
                        {"note_id":4,"content":"This is note 4","created":"2015-06-02 15:49:26"}
                ];

    $(document).ready(
            function() {    
                var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({   
                                 data: notes,
                                 schema: {
                                   model: {
                                   id: "note_id",
                                   fields: {
                                    note_id: { type: "number" },
                                    content: { type: "string" },
                                    created: { type: "date" }
                                   }
                                }
                            }});

                var listView = $("#notes-list").kendoListView({
                    dataSource: dataSource, 
                    template: kendo.template($("#NoteTemplate").html()),
                    editTemplate: kendo.template($("#NoteEditTemplate").html()) 
                }).data("kendoListView");
      });
  </script>

  <div id="notes-list"></div>
```

Comment: after making those changes, the issue of the wrong model instance being passed to the edit template still remains... https://dojo.telerik.com/oNosOCUv/10

Comment: @Black I made one more change forgot to mention that have edited my answer